# How to break string into chunks by parentheses order?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

**Program description:** I'm trying to create a function `breakInChunks()`, which accepts one parameter `temp_s: string`, where `temp_s` is a math expression, e.g. `1+(3-e^(x-6))-8+(99-4)*10`. The function then searches for opening and closing parentheses and replaces expression inside them with a 'chunk' in the following format: `[i$j]` (where i is an index of the opening bracket and j - of the closing one). If there are several chunks inside one whole chunk `[m$n]`, the program should only replace characters in the string from `m` to `n` with `[m$n]`. In the end the function returns `keypairs` dictionary, where key should be chunks and values should be actual strings that have been cut from initial string, e.g. `{'23$28': 'string within 23 and 28 characters'}`. All the remaining symbols (that were outside parentheses) should be appended to the dictionary in the end in the same `chunk: string` way.

**breakInChunks() input:** `(7+x+8*(9+10(11+12)+14))-(2*(34))`

**breakInChunks() output:** `{'12$18': '11+12', '7$22': '9+10[12$18]+14', '0$23': '7+x+8*[7$22]', '28$31': '34', '25$32': '2*[28$31]', '24:25': '-'}`

**Problem:** When trying to read more complex strings I'm starting to get very odd results. For example:

```
Input: (7+y+(66+7)+(32+(78*19-(32-0)))+(32-9))+8+9+(9-10)-(9/7)-10
Output: {'5$10': '66+7', '23$28': '32-0', '16$29': '78*19-[23$28', '12$30': 
'32+[16$29]))+8+9+', '32$37': '32-9', '0$38': '7+y+(66+7)+(32+[16$29][23$28]]37]])+8',
'44$49': '9-10', '51$55': '9/7', '11:0': '', '31:0': '', '39:44': '+8+9+', '50:51': '-'}
```

Basically, when there are different independent chunks inside a chunk the program starts combing them and not leaving only one outer chunk. I've been trying to understand the reason behind it, but every time I try changing the program the problem always stayed the same. I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
def findall(sstr, substr):
    gen = sstr.find(substr)
    while gen != -1:
        yield gen
        gen = sstr.find(substr, gen + 1)


def findclosest(l: list, el: list):  # find closest string from L to string from EL
    j = el[ 1 ]
    minimum = j
    min_index = 0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[ i ][ 0 ] - j < minimum:
            minimum = l[ i ][ 0 ] - j
            min_index = l[ i ][ 0 ]
    return min_index


def breakInChunks(temp_s):  # main
    list_of_additions = [ ]
    list_of_opened = list(findall(temp_s, '('))
    list_of_closed = list(findall(temp_s, ')'))
    if sum(list_of_opened) < sum(list_of_closed) and len(list_of_opened) == len(
            list_of_closed):
        n = 0
        # <WHILE>
        while len(
                list_of_closed) != 0:  # read strings-expressions from the most inner ones to the most outer ones
            minimum = list_of_closed[ len(list_of_closed) - 1 ]
            j = list_of_closed.pop(0)
            for i in range(len(list_of_opened)):  # find the closest opening bracket to the most inner closing one
                diff = j - list_of_opened[ i ]
                if diff > 0:
                    if diff <= minimum:
                        pop_index = i
                        minimum = j - list_of_opened[ i ]
                else:
                    break
            starting_index = list_of_opened.pop(pop_index)
            # start filling KEYPAIRS
            if len(keypairs) == 0:  # if KEYPAIRS is empty
                keypairs[ f'{starting_index}${j}' ] = temp_s[ starting_index + 1:j ]
            else:  # if KEYPAIRS has at least one key-value pair
                keys = [ key.split('$') for key in
                         keypairs.keys() ]  # reading and unpacking key-value pairs (reading indecies)
                innerSeq = temp_s
                min_index_i = None
                min_index_j = None
                prevExtracted_i = 0
                prevExtracted_j = 0
                for p in range(len(keys) - 1, -1, -1):
                    k = keys[ p ]
                    extracted_i, extracted_j = int(k[ 0 ]), int(k[ 1 ])
                    if starting_index < extracted_i:  # if the chunk we are checking contains another one, we are checking if it's in fact the closest one to the chunk we are checking
                        if (
                                extracted_i < prevExtracted_i and prevExtracted_j < extracted_j) or prevExtracted_i == 0:
                            min_index_i = extracted_i
                            min_index_j = extracted_j
                            if prevExtracted_i == 0:
                                if extracted_i > int(keys[ p - 1 ][ 0 ]) and extracted_j < int(keys[ p - 1 ][ 1 ]):
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    innerSeq = innerSeq[
                                               :extracted_i ] + f'[{extracted_i}${extracted_j}]' + innerSeq[
                                                                                                   extracted_j + 1: ]
                        else:
                            if min_index_i is not None:
                                innerSeq = innerSeq[ :min_index_i ] + f'[{min_index_i}${min_index_j}]' + innerSeq[
                                                                                                         min_index_j + 1: ]
                                min_index_i = None
                                min_index_j = None
                            else:
                                innerSeq = innerSeq[
                                           :prevExtracted_i ] + f'[{prevExtracted_i}${prevExtracted_j}]' + innerSeq[
                                                                                                           prevExtracted_j + 1: ]
    
                        prevExtracted_i = extracted_i
                        prevExtracted_j = extracted_j
                        n += 1
    
                keypairs[ f'{starting_index}${j}' ] = innerSeq[ starting_index + 1:j ]
    
        # </WHILE>
    
        # checking if there are any strings outside parentheses left
        temp = [ [ int(key.split('$')[ 0 ]), int(key.split('$')[ 1 ]) ] for key in sorted(keypairs.keys(),
                                                                                          key=lambda el: int(
                                                                                              el.split('$')[
                                                                                                  1 ])) ]  # sort from the most inner to the most outer
        for i in range(len(temp) - 1):
            if temp[ i ][ 1 ] < temp[ i + 1 ][
                0 ]:  # if there is a gap between parentheses
                # find the closest difference in order to find actual string outside chunks with the help of findclosest()
                # add new chunk to LIST_OF_ADDITIONS
                list_of_additions.append([ temp[ i ][ 1 ] + 1, findclosest(temp[ i + 1: ], temp[ i ]) ])
    
        if len(list_of_additions) > 0:  # if something is inside LIST_OF_ADDITIONS
            # add remaining strings to KEYPAIRS
            for addition in list_of_additions:
                keypairs[ f'{addition[ 0 ]}:{addition[ 1 ]}' ] = self.s[ addition[ 0 ]:addition[ 1 ] ]
    
        return keypairs  # return KEYPAIRS
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f'Amount of closing and opening brackets does not match')
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to write an expression parser.  This is a well-understood problem and there is a lot of available literature on the topic.

Comment: Nested parenthesis pairs are usually parsed using a stack or a recursion. Both approaches are theoretically equivalent. (One can rewrite recursive code to stack based code and vice versa)

Comment: _Really_, use a real parser generator for this. Anything else (when built by someone without enough formal computer science background to know the state of the art) is taking an efficiency hit and taking on a bunch of potential maintenance load. There's a huge variety of options; see https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing -- or take a formal computer science course; typically parser construction is taught in a 300-level class with a title like "compiler design", though you don't need that to _use_ the tools, just to build them yourself.

Comment: You are actually skipping a step. First parse the original string to produce an AST, *then* "evaluate" the AST to produce your dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a stack to accumulate sub-expressions at each level of nested parentheses is a common way to approach this.  Store the position of the opening parenthesis and the accumulated expression string at each level.  Add a level when you encounter an opening parenthesis.  Pop out the current level and add it to the result when you encounter a closing parenthesis.  At that point the substitution token is added to the previous level's expression (which becomes the current level).

```
def parGroups(S):
    result = dict()
    stack  = [[0,""]]*2           # parenthesis position, expression
    for i,c in enumerate(S+")"):  # extra ")" to force out main expression
        if c=="(":                
            stack.append([i,""])  # stack up new group
            continue
        if c==")":
            start,expr      = stack.pop(-1)    # unstack current group
            c               = f"[{start}${i}]" # token
            result[c[1:-1]] = expr             # build result
        stack[-1][-1] += c        # accumulate expression in current group
    return result
```

Output:

```
S = "(7+y+(66+7)+(32+(78*19-(32-0)))+(32-9))+8+9+(9-10)-(9/7)-10"
print(parGroups(S))

{'5$10' : '66+7',
 '23$28': '32-0',
 '16$29': '78*19-[23$28]',
 '12$30': '32+[16$29]',
 '32$37': '32-9',
 '0$38' : '7+y+[5$10]+[12$30]+[32$37]',
 '44$49': '9-10',
 '51$55': '9/7',
 '0$59' : '[0$38]+8+9+[44$49]-[51$55]-10'}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but where exactly do you define `oper`?

Comment: My bad it was supposed to be `expr`, partial rename in an attempt to be more precise in my variable names. (fixed now)

Answer (score 1):

I would tokenise the input using a regular expression, and process the tokens using recursion:

```
import re

def breakInChunks(s):
    chunks = dict()
    tokens = re.finditer(r"([^()]+|.?)", s)

    def recur(start):
        result = ""
        for match in tokens:
            if match[0] in ")":
                key = f"{start}${match.start()}"
                chunks[key] = result
                return key
            result += f"[{recur(match.start())}]" if match[0] == "(" else match[0]
        
    recur(0)
    return chunks
```

For your example:

```
s = "(7+x+8*(9+10(11+12)+14))-(2*(34))"
chunks = breakInChunks(s)
```

`chunks` will be:

```
{
    '12$18': '11+12',
    '7$22': '9+10[12$18]+14',
    '0$23': '7+x+8*[7$22]',
    '28$31': '34', '25$32':
    '2*[28$31]',
    '0$33': '[0$23]-[25$32]'
}
```

Note that the last entry will not be `'24:25': '-'` as given in your question, but `'0$33': '[0$23]-[25$32]'`, which is more consistent with the logic applied for the other entries.

For the more complex example:

```
s = "(7+y+(66+7)+(32+(78*19-(32-0)))+(32-9))+8+9+(9-10)-(9/7)-10"
chunks = breakInChunks(s)
```

`chunks` now is:

```
{
    '5$10': '66+7',
    '23$28': '32-0',
    '16$29': '78*19-[23$28]',
    '12$30': '32+[16$29]',
    '32$37': '32-9',
    '0$38': '7+y+[5$10]+[12$30]+[32$37]',
    '44$49': '9-10',
    '51$55': '9/7',
    '0$59': '[0$38]+8+9+[44$49]-[51$55]-10'
}
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code and I really appreciate your answer, but the approach without 3d party libraries seemed more suitable to me. Also, I was looking more for approaches related to stacks.

Comment: OK. I just want to mention that `re` is not a third party library. It belongs to the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).